# How can I write a sentence converse algorithm using higher level C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

run this code.
you can reverse "live long and prosper" to "prosper and long live"
.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void rev(char *l, char *r);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char buf[] = "live long and prosper";
char *end, *x, *y;

// Reverse the whole sentence first..
for(end=buf; *end; end++);
rev(buf,end-1); 


// Now swap each word within sentence...
x = buf-1; 
y = buf; 

while(x++ < end)
{
if(*x == '\0' || *x == ' ')
{
rev(y,x-1);
y = x+1;
}
} 

// Now print the final string....
printf("%s\n",buf);

return(0);
}


// Function to reverse a string in place...
void rev(char *l,char *r) 
{
char t;
while(l < r) 
{ 
t = *l; 
*l++ = *r; 
*r-- = t; 
}
}
```

I want to know, in C++ by using  header, is there any good quick way to do this?
thanks!

Comment: You could do this better in C using `strtok`...

Comment: C or C++? The answer will be very different depending on the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::istringstream converter("live long and prosper");

    std::vector<std::string> words(
        (std::istream_iterator<std::string>(converter)), 
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

    std::copy(words.rbegin(), words.rend(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

Efficiency is harder to guess at. Even though they produce relatively little output, both are undoubtedly I/O bound, but the relatively speed of iostreams to C streams depends heavily on the implementation. It can go either way -- at one time, iostreams were almost always slower, often significantly so. Nowadays, it's *fairly* frequent for iostreams to be faster (e.g., [libraw](http://www.softpedia.com/progChangelog/LibRaw-Changelog-98795.html) recent switched to iostreams specifically to improve speed -- and it worked).

The internal manipulations are probably even less certain. Some (many?) implementations of `std::string` include what's called the short string optimization ("SSO"). This allocates a small (e.g., 20 byte) block of storage as part of the string object itself. If the string is short enough to fit there, this avoids a separate allocation for the content. Likewise, `std::vector` allocates raw memory in blocks, and then creates strings in-place in that memory. Given the small size and number of strings involved here, there's a pretty fair chance that all the memory for the entire vector of strings is allocated as a single block in one allocation. In this case, this stands a pretty good chance of being faster than the C version -- in your C version, each byte of input is copied once to reverse the whole string, and again to reverse individual words, whereas this copies each only once. OTOH, if you had more strings, or they were longer (too long to fit in the SSO area) you'd have more dynamic allocation, which would probably slow things down (though exactly how much is hard to estimate, and obviously depends on the heap manager...)

At the same time, this certainly uses more memory, and depending on exactly how that memory is allocated, it might use more dynamic memory allocation (e.g., if the initial allocation for `std::vector` is fewer than 4 items, and/or your string doesn't include SSO).

The bottom line is that the speed of the C++ version depends much more on the quality of the implementation. With an old compiler/standard library (e.g., gcc 2.x, VC++ 6) I'd expect it to be slower -- possibly quite a lot slower. With a current implementation, I'd expect it to be faster -- possibly quite a bit faster. The difference between the slowest and fastest implementations might easily be 4:1 (most of that in the iostreams implementation though).

Answer (score 6):

You might want to use the `std::reverse` function, provided in the `<algorithm>` header file.

Comment: @user658266: Quicker?  For you to write, test, and debug the program, probably, since the biggest chunk is tested for you already.  For the computer to execute, likely not.